# Rake Tasks With Tiny_TDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, tiny-tds

I'm trying to access some data from our on-site billing server to be populate into a rails app that i'm deploying. I've done some digging about and think Tiny TDS and a rake task is the best way to go but I seem to be getting a bit stuck. The code showed below is just an example and not finished! I keep getting a server name not found in configuration files error.

task :import_customers do

```
RAILS_HOME = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"../.."))

RAILS_CONFIG = "#{RAILS_HOME}/config"

require "#{RAILS_CONFIG}/environment"

require 'tiny_tds'

client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => 'user', :password => 'pass', :host => 'SQLSRVR')

result = client.execute("select sitedetails.siteid, company.id as companyid, sitedetails.shortname, company.name,sitedetails.sitename as [Site Name] from company inner join sitedetails on company.id=sitedetails.id left outer join solutionscustinfo s on sitedetails.siteid=s.siteid left outer join paymentconditions a on s.paymentconditions_id=a.id left outer join company agent on company.agent_id=agent.id left outer join sitecontacts billingcontact on billingcontact.contactid=s.billingcontact_id left outer join package p on p.id=package left outer join tariffnames v on v.tariffcode=isnull(s.lcr_tariff,p.lcr_tariff) left outer join tariffnames d on d.tariffcode=isnull(s.data_tariff,p.data_tariff) left outer join tariffnames m on m.tariffcode=isnull(s.mob_tariff,p.mob_tariff) left outer join (select invoiceaddress from sitedetails group by invoiceaddress) ba on ba.invoiceaddress=sitedetails.siteid left outer join discount on discount.id=isnull(s.discount,p.discount) left outer join billrun on billrun.id=s.bill_run left outer join report_profile on report_profile.id=s.report_profile left outer join account_manager on account_manager.id=company.acctmgr_id where company.is_customer<>0 order by company.name,sitedetails.shortname")

result.each do |row|

    puts row

    name = row['name']

    sitename = row['Site Name']

    puts sitename

    @company = Company.all

end
```

end

Comment: Are your ruby app and your server on the same machine??

Comment: do you have a `[SQLSRVR]` section defined in your freetds.conf file? Post the relevant config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not replying I went about this in a different way in the end.

namespace :abillity do

```
desc "import customers"

def return_address(siteid)

 client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => 'earth', :password => 'gs500e', :host => '192.168.1.38')

 result = client.execute("select Address, Town, County, PostCode from sitedetails WHERE SiteID = '#{siteid}'")

 result.each do |row|

    if (row['Address'] == nil or row['Town'] == nil or row['County'] == nil or row['PostCode'] == nil)

        return "Not Listed"

    end

    @address = row['Address'] + " " + row['Town'] + " " + row['County'] + " " + row['PostCode']

    if (@address == nil)

        return "Not Listed"

    elsif (@address.strip == "")

        return "Not Listed"

    else

        return @address

    end

    return ""

 end

end
```

task :import_customers => :environment do

```
require 'tiny_tds'

require 'rubygems'





client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => 'earth', :password => 'gs500e', :host => '192.168.1.38')

result = client.execute("select sitedetails.siteid, company.id as companyid, sitedetails.shortname, company.name,sitedetails.sitename as [Site Name],sitedetails.sage_id as [Account No] from company inner join sitedetails on company.id=sitedetails.id left outer join solutionscustinfo s on sitedetails.siteid=s.siteid left outer join paymentconditions a on s.paymentconditions_id=a.id left outer join company agent on company.agent_id=agent.id left outer join sitecontacts billingcontact on billingcontact.contactid=s.billingcontact_id left outer join package p on p.id=package left outer join tariffnames v on v.tariffcode=isnull(s.lcr_tariff,p.lcr_tariff) left outer join tariffnames d on d.tariffcode=isnull(s.data_tariff,p.data_tariff) left outer join tariffnames m on m.tariffcode=isnull(s.mob_tariff,p.mob_tariff) left outer join (select invoiceaddress from sitedetails group by invoiceaddress) ba on ba.invoiceaddress=sitedetails.siteid left outer join discount on discount.id=isnull(s.discount,p.discount) left outer join billrun on billrun.id=s.bill_run left outer join report_profile on report_profile.id=s.report_profile left outer join account_manager on account_manager.id=company.acctmgr_id where company.is_customer<>0 order by company.name,sitedetails.shortname")

result.each do |row|



    # First of all check if a company allready exists that has the same name and site name

    existing = Company.where(["name = ?",row['name']]).where(["site = ?",row['Site Name']]).limit(1)

    if (row['Account No'] == nil or row['Account No'] == "")

        row['Account No'] = "N/A"

    end

    if (existing.first == nil)

        # Company does not exist add it

        @company = Company.new

        @company.name = row['name']

        @company.site = row['Site Name'] 

        @company.accountNumber = row['Account No']

        @company.address = return_address(row['siteid'])

        @company.companytype = "Customer"

        if (@company.save! == false)

            debugger

        end

    else    

        # Existing, make sure acct no and address is up to date

        @company = existing[0]

        @company.accountNumber = row['Account No']

        @company.address = return_address(row['siteid'])

        @company.save



    end









end
```

end

end